# How do I add Hibernate to an existing Eclipse project? Is Hibernate the same as JPA?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, configuration

I have searched.  I can't find the exact way that matches what I have.  I installed Eclipse for Java EE.  I then went to help and install new software.  Put in the jboss url, downloaded the Hibernate libraries.  Everything went fine.  I also installed the JDBC driver for MySQL.  I tested it.  It works.  Downloaded and installed slf4j because I read someone that said to (hey, I'm learning).

I started a new Java EE project, and uh, I'm kind of stuck after that.  It's a "Hello World" at the moment.

I can't find out what to do.  I've seen tutorials where it says create a Hibernate project, but what if I want to add it later after I start a "normal" project?  I don't want to manually look for the Hibernate.jar in the download folder.  I installed it and want to know how to get to it.

I also saw lots of things that said JPA and Hibernate.  Are they the same thing?

EDIT:  I was able to find Hibernate by right clicking on the project, new, scroll down to hibernate.  I am still interested in JPA and Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA stands for "Java Persistence API", and it is a ***specification***. It basically defines the APIs and behaviors of a persistence layer, and there are different ***implementations*** of the JPA specification. Hibernate is one of these implementations. There are a few others, e.g.:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/overview/index.html

http://openjpa.apache.org/

The JPA specification can be found here:
http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/index.html